# Determine Button Background Image - Objective-C (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a view controller with different buttons with background images assigned. My header file looks as follows:

```
@interface ImageSelect : UIViewController

- (IBAction)ImageButton:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)Done:(id)sender;

@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIImage *currentImage;

@end
```

And the section of my main file that contains the button method looks like:

```
- (IBAction)ImageButton:(id)sender {

    if ([@"railway-336702_1280.jpg" isEqual:self.currentImage]) {

        img = @"railway-336702_1280.jpg";
        NSLog(@"Test");
    }

}
```

I am wanting to save the image name to a NSString called img. Currently, the code runs but doesn't actually perform the save to img.

Comment: Why not subclass UIButton and add a property called `NSString * imageName` and check that?

Comment: Is 'Test' logged to the console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158737/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-backgroundimage-from-a-button -- it looks like there is no good way besides subclassing.

Comment: @"railway-336702_1280.jpg" its not image object but its string . you can make a image by [UIImage imageNamed:@"railway-336702_1280.jpg"]. then try to check it.

Comment: @danh Img is declared at the top of my main file like so: NSString *img;

Comment: I am using a storyboard and setting background images of buttons through it. Should I do this another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way would be: if you simply wanted to check whether the `UIButton` contains that image that you set, you could simply use the `tag` property:

Let say you set its image with an image named: railway-336702_1280.jpg

Set the `tag` with something simpler like "1280".

Then check this `tag` against an Integer. And should you change the image again, change the `tag` correspondingly.

```
if (((UIButton*)sender).tag == 1280) 
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is simpler for sure. My guess is he wants to load the UIImage and thus would need the full image name. If not, then this is the way to go.

Comment: @SandyChapman Good catch, sure, but I would use a dictionary in such case and then have let say "1280" (or something else) as key and the full path as value and set the image dynamically using that.

Comment: @Unheilig I can see the use in that, however, I think it's easier if for whatever reason you want to change the image to then just update the user defined runtime attribute in IB instead of having to jump into the code to find the dictionary key and edit its value. My solution would be more to just do it all dynamically and place the images in a folder.

Answer (score 1):

Once a UIImage is created it loses all connection to the file it was loaded from. You cannot determine at runtime what the background image is.

If you need to get the name at runtime, subclass UIButton and then create a property called imageName and set it using the User Defined Runtime Attributes through Interface Builder.

Example:

In ImageSelectButton.m:

```
@interface ImageSelectButton ()

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *imageName;

@end
```

In ImageSelect.m:

```
@interface ImageSelect

...

- (IBAction)ImageButton:(ImageSelectButton*)sender {
    if ([sender.imageName isEqualToString:@"railway-336702_1280.jpg"]) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
...
```

In Interface Builder when selecting your UIButton set the Custom Class and runtime attribute:

[image]

Comment: Ok. Starting to understand. Implemented your code and got: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIButton 0x15d608b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ImageName.' Did I do something incorrectly?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add you'll need to set your Custom Class for your buttons to ImageSelectButton. I'll update my answer with a screenshot for you.