# How to get the background image name of a button by sub classing UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I want to get the background image name of the button when taping it. After searching a lot in internet i found that

> Since UIImage does not store the name of the image it contains,
>   . We have to store the name elsewhere by yourself in
>   relationship to the Button or image

via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158737/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-backgroundimage-from-a-button) SO answer. However i want to know how to get the background image name of button by sub classing  UIButton? What method i need to over ride from UIButton to get the background image name?

Button's tag,Title text and accessibilityIdentifier am using already for other purpose. So i left with no option other than getting the image name.

My app supports from iOS 7 to latest.

Comment: Create a UIImage category that has a NSString property?

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to override. Also where does the image name come from? are you creating the button programmatically or using storyboard. Either way why don't you just create a category and add additional property that says image name.

Comment: @Vig am using storyboard to set the button image.

Comment: If you are using storyboard I don't think there is a way to actually get the image name(at least not that I know of). I am assuming you are also setting the background image using storyboard?

Comment: @Vig yes correct am setting background image also using story board

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the image name within an instance of UIImage itself by using a category.

Add a new category on UIImage called ImageName and add a property to it:

```
//UIImage+ImageName.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (ImageName)

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *imgName;

@end
```

Then, you can simply attach the name of the image to any UIImage by importing the category.

```
#import "UIImage+ImageName.h"

NSString *name = @"someImage.jpg";
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
image.imgName = name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since UIImage does not store the name of the image it contains, you can't. You have to store the name elsewhere by yourself in relationship to the Button or image.

[How to get the name of the backgroundImage from a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158737/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-backgroundimage-from-a-button)

Comment: I have already seen this answer and even I have marked the same in my question