# Find the Name of a Background Image of a Button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have named a set of images like this:

Unselected:

> nameOfTheImage

Selected:

> nameOfTheImage~

In order to change the background image of a button, my code is written to take the string of the background image's name, and either append or take off the "`~`" to change it to the correct image.

So I tried this:

```
let backgroundString = String(selector.currentBackgroundImage!)
print(backgroundString)
```

But I get this:

```
<UIImage: 0x146d98b80>, {485, 300}
```

Is there any way to get the plain name of the background image?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this isn't possible to get the `name` of the `background image` of a `uibutton`. refer these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158737/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-backgroundimage-from-a-button . as a suggestion, how about to use `uiimageview` instead of a `button background image`

Comment: @AnuradhS Do you get image name from `UIImageView`?

Comment: nope, but it is easy to change images by checking which one is displaying than checking button background image

Comment: can you show the code of button

Comment: What do you intend to do? You can set background image differentely by state of `UIButton` i.e.. `UIControlStateSelected`..

Comment: @K.Nimo I have twelve buttons on the interface, which all start of unselected. They are dragged in my viewController as outlets and actions. The action passes in the UIButton to a function that is shared with all of the other buttons. I have twenty-four images including an unselected image (white background, orange content) and a selected image (orange background, white content) with an extra "~" at the end of it. If the string of the image name has "~" at the end, it is dropped off to change the image. If the image doesn't have "~" at the end, "~" is appended to change the image.

Comment: @K.Nimo The end goal is to have a dictionary with information about which buttons are selected and which buttons aren't selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had a similar problem. Fortunately I know the state of the button when the viewcontroller is displayed, so I created a String control, which was something like this:

```
var buttonState = "not selected"
```

then when the user clicks on the button I check:

```
if (buttonState == "not selected") {

   // change buttonState to "selected"

   // change the image of the button

}
```

Comment: Why use a string instead of a bool?

Answer (score 1):

I just dealt with a somewhat similar problem. You can use: `buttonName.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "backgroundImageName"), for: .normal)`
Where here .normal is the state of the button, so you can adjust your state accordingly.

For anyone else who might be having this problem, this is for Swift5.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to retrieve the button's background image name by doing the following:

```
let imgDesc : String = button.currentBackgroundImage!.description
```

The above string (imgDesc) always contains something similar to the following:

```
<UIImage:0x281646400 named(main: userBike) {40, 63}>
```

Using prefix I drop everything after the close parenthesis in a new string variable:

```
var imgName = imgDesc.prefix { $0 != ")" } //always contains only one close parenthesis
```

Using range I retrieve the index of where "(main: " is located within my imgName variable:

```
let index = imgName.range(of: "(main: ")?.upperBound //always contains open parenthesis followed by main:<space>
```

Using the index from above I drop everything before it:

```
imgName = imgName.suffix(from: index!)
```

This ultimately isolates the image name from button.currentBackgroundImage.description:

```
print(imgName) //prints userBike
```

Prints "userBike" which is the image name successfully isolated from imgDesc.

Comment: Sorry.  Not sure what I did wrong.  Is it not an answer?

Comment: No, everything seems good.

Comment: All I meant, was that I tried to think of a way to prevent it from breaking in the future if the output of currentBackgroundImage.description ever changed.